# Are there any built-in methods to find the input from the output ?

Tags: python, function, inverse

As a beginner of python, I am curious about how can we compute inverse of a function. If the function which I use is one-to-one and onto, are there any methods which I can rebuilt function's input from the output I have ? Which will ease our job to write another code for inverse function. 
 I would appreciate any ideas

Comment: Do you mean a mathematical function?

Comment: Any function that is bijective.

Comment: There's nothing that does this automatically. Most functions are not reversible like this, so there's not much value in it.

Comment: Except for well-known built-in functions, this might even be equivalent to the Halting Problem.

Comment: How would you imagine this would work in the general case? Suppose the function performs a table lookup, how can it know whether the values are always unique so that the lookup table can be inverted?

Comment: Does it need to always check if  there are any two values that are same while operating on table lookup ?